# Is it always possible to complete a pass or score a goal?

Tags: android, football-legends

I've been playing [Flick Kick Football Legends](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pikpok.fkf2.play) on my android phone lately. For those unfamilar with this game you have to flick a football past defenders to another player on your team. The game constructs mostly static scenes with your player usually behind a defender or two. Sometimes the players on both teams move from side to side in a fixed pattern. Your players can get various skills including harder kicks and better curves.

Anyway, upon occasion the game constructs an arrangement of players that I believe it impossible to successfully pass the ball to your player without it being intercepted by the CPU player.

Is this the case, or is every arrangement possible if only I flick and swerve the football in exactly the right way?